# Erro "[ ] cannot be converted to JSON" ao tentar criar JSONObject a partir de String

Tags: json, gson, kotlin

Estou utilizando a linguagem Kotlin juntamente com a biblioteca GSON para realizar criação/parse de objestos JSON.

Eu tenho a seguinte string que aramazena um objeto JSON retornado de um server

```
val jsonString = "{"age":22,"height":1.8,"profession":"Student","at_room":false,"gender":"male","pictures":[ ]}"
```

Quando tento converter essa string para um JSON Object, fazendo

```
val jsonData = JsonParser().parse(jsonString).asJsonObject
```

eu recebo o seguinte erro: `[] cannot be converted to JSON`

Acho que o erro se deve ao fato de `pictures` ser um JSONArray e não um tipo primitivo, mas de qualquer forma eu gostaria de saber como converter essa string para um JSON Object corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o erro, e infelizmente, não tinha a ver com a transformação da String em um JSON Object, **mas sim na conversão das propriedades da classe User para um JSON String**

A minha função que fazia essa conversão era a seguinte

```
override fun userToJson(user: User): String {

    return jsonObject(

            AGE_FIELD to user.age,
            HEIGHT_FIELD to user.height,
            EDUCATION_FIELD to user.education,
            WORK_FIELD to user.work,
            ABOUT_FIELD to user.about,
            GENDER_FIELD to user.gender,

            /* O erro era lançado nesta última linha */
            PICTURES_FIELD to jsonArray(user.albumPics)

    ).toString()
}
```

A analisar a função `jsonArray()` vi que ela recebe como parâmetro um conjunto de valores ( e.g. `jsonArray("a","b","c")` ), porém, eu estava passando um `user.albumPics`, que é um objeto do tipo `MutableList<String>`.

Portanto, o que eu deveria fazer era converter `user.albumPics` para uma representação em String fazendo `user.albumPics.toString()`, dessa forma, a chamada da função ficava `jsonArray("[]")` , o que é válido.

Assim, a solução final foi realizar uma pequena alteração na linha

```
PICTURES_FIELD to jsonArray(user.albumPics)
```

substituindo por

```
PICTURES_FIELD to jsonArray(user.albumPics.toString())
```